# Rails decrypt and search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx, encryption

In rails, it is necessary for me that when i store items into my database i encrypt all data first. When i search the data what i am planning to do is decrypting some of the data to make it searchable. I need to know if this is a good idea. in my controller i am planning something like this (using thinking sphinx)

```
People.find_each do |person|
  person.name = decrypt(person.name) #using some tool im unsure of yet
  person.job = decrypt(person.job)
end

@people = People.search params[:search]
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to accomplish what i need though. I dont know what kind of behaviour would have for many searches conducted at once. I also dont know if this secure.

By the way, it is absolutely necessary to encrypt **ALL** (i guess excluding default attributes like id and created at) data, because my team is demanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're encrypting all data in the database, then you're going to need to decrypt via SQL, because Sphinx talks to your database using SQL, not via your Rails app or anything else in Ruby.

I've no idea what tools there are available for encrypt/decryption in MySQL or PostgreSQL, but this may be more pain than it's worth.